# How to stay DRY whilst using LINQ to Entities and helper methods?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Lets say that I have a particular way of deciding whether some strings "match", like this:

```
public bool stringsMatch(string searchFor, string searchIn)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFor))
  {
    return true;
  }

  return searchIn != null &&
    (searchIn.Trim().ToLower().StartsWith(searchFor.Trim().ToLower()) ||
     searchIn.Contains(" " + searchFor));
}
```

I would like to pull matches out of a database using Linq To Entities and this helper. However, when I try this:

```
IQueryable<Blah> blahs = query.Where(b => stringsMatch(searchText, b.Name);
```

I get "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method..."

If I re-write the code as:

```
IQueryable<Blah> blahs = query.Where(b =>
      string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) ||
      (b.Name != null &&
        (b.Name.Trim().ToLower().StartsWith(searchText.Trim().ToLower()) ||
         b.Name.Contains(" " + searchText)));
```

Which is logically equivalent, then things work fine. The problem is that the code isn't as readable, and I have to re-write it for each different entity I want to match.

As far as I can tell from questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042668/given-linq-to-entities-does-not-support-custom-methods-how-do-you-stay-dry), what I want to do is impossible at the moment, but I'm hoping that I'm missing something, am I?

Comment: try [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a freely available library called [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) (as mentioned by @Eranga) this task becomes reasonable. Using LINQKit the code I have now looks like:

```
protected Expression<Func<T, bool>> stringsMatch(string searchFor, Expression<Func<T, string>> searchIn)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFor))
  {
    return e => true;
  }

  return
    e =>
    (searchIn.Invoke(e) != null &&
      (searchIn.Invoke(e).Trim().ToLower().StartsWith(searchFor.Trim().ToLower()) ||
       searchIn.Invoke(e).Contains(" " + searchFor)));
}
```

And needs to be called like this (note the AsExpandable() call)

```
IQueryable<Blah> blahs = query().AsExpandable().Where(StringsMatch(searchText, b => b.Name));
```

The magic parts are the searchIn.Invoke(e) calls and the use of AsExpandable() which adds a wrapper layer that allows them to work.

The AsExpandable() bit is explained in detail by the original author [here](http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx).

Note that I'm still a bit hazy on some of the details of expressions, so please add a comment/edit this answer if it can be made better/shorter/clearer.

Answer (score 5):

If all the 'blahs' (classes) that you will be filtering have the same structure, you can use a simple method like this.  The main difference is that it returns an Expression that Linq should be able to parse and it brings in the whole instance and filters on Name instead of bringing in just the string name.

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildStringMatch<T>(string searchFor) where T : IHasName
    {
        return b =>
              string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFor) ||
              (b.Name != null &&
                (b.Name.Trim().ToLower().StartsWith(searchFor.Trim().ToLower()) ||
                 b.Name.Contains(" " + searchFor)));
    }
```

You can use that method like this:

```
    IQueryable<Blah> blahs = query.Where(BuildStringMatch<Blah>(searchText));
```

That assumes all your classes that you'd want to filter on implement some interface such as:

```
    public interface IHasName
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }
```

If you want to be filtering on different properties, I don't think that's something you can do with simple code like this.  I believe you'll need to build the Expression yourself with reflection (or with the help of a library that uses reflection) - it's still possible but much more difficult.

Edit:  It sounds like you need dynamic behavior, so I borrowed some logic from [dtb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76217/dtb)'s answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431617/creating-dynamic-predicates-passing-in-property-to-a-function-as-parameter/3431670#3431670) and came up with this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildStringMatch<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> property, string searchFor)
{
    var searchForExpression = Expression.Constant(searchFor, typeof(string));
    return
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.OrElse(
                Expression.Call(typeof(string), "IsNullOrEmpty", null, searchForExpression),
                Expression.AndAlso(
                    Expression.NotEqual(property.Body, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(string))),
                    Expression.OrElse(
                        Expression.Call(Expression.Call(Expression.Call(property.Body, "Trim", null), "ToLower", null), "StartsWith", null,
                            Expression.Call(Expression.Call(searchForExpression, "Trim", null), "ToLower", null)),
                        Expression.Call(property.Body, "Contains", null, Expression.Call(typeof(string), "Concat", null, Expression.Constant(" "), searchForExpression))
                    )
                )
            ),
            property.Parameters
        );
}
```

You would use it like:

```
        IQueryable<Blah> blahs2 = query.Where(BuildStringMatch<Blah>(b => b.Name, searchText));
```

It's long and verbose but you can see how it's similiar to the original method written in straight C# code.  Note:  I didn't test this code, so there could be a few small problems - but that is the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I did consider something like this, but the lack of flexibility is off-putting (not everything I want to match is called "Name"). Any hints on where to start with the more complicated way?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some sample code.  It certainly looks more complicated but if you only have to write it once.....maybe it won't be so bad.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful (shame I can only upvote once). However, I've found some other code in our codebase that uses a library called LINQKit to do something very similar in (I think) a neater way. I'll add a new answer with the full details.